# Do squids or octopus suffer from myopia(hyperopia)? Do other vertebrates get myopia(hyperopia)?

Tags: evolution, zoology, eyes, human-eye

Both vertebrates and cephalopods evolved very sophisticated camera-type eyes, and both are capable of focus. But it also pose a risk of inability of focusing, such as myopia in human. So is myopia a common problem of vertebrate eyes or just occurred in a few vertebrate species?

Cephalopods also have the ability of focusing, but they focus in a different way. They focus by changing the distance between lens and retina, instead of contracting the lens like human. So are cephalopod eyes more flexible and less prone to get myopia?